# Safari isn't measuring height of div corectly with jQuery .height()

Tags: jquery, safari

When I run the following jQuery to find the height of a div that contains several images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    var scroll = $('#scroll').height();
    ...
});
```

this works in both FF and Chrome. Safari however always returns a result of 18px. I assume Safari is measuring the div before the images have loaded but I'm not sure though. Anyway to get Safari to return the same result as FF/Chrome?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wait until all the image are loaded by using the window.onload handler :

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    ...
    var scroll = $('#scroll').height();
    ...
});
```